# How to effectively debug uncaught exception in asyncrhonous programming?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012

I got this error

[image]

I used to be able to debug this easily. The program usually stop at when the exception occurs.

However, after I go async await, the program would break on the top async sub that calls the whole thing. I do not know which object has nullreference exception.

I want the program to break when the exception is thrown. Not all the way up.

finRepatOrderingAsync is a very big function that calls another async function and another and another

Comment: Did you bother to look at the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: What's your setting for the exception?  Break when thrown, or only break when uncaught?  If it's the latter, have you tried the former?  (In VS 2017, go to Debug / Windows / Exceptions or Ctrl-Alt-E to change the exception settings.)